# Prism mobile phone metadata: does it include location?

Tags: mobile, metadata, big-data

I've read that [Prism collects metadata](http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2013/06/09/190092800/bush-era-nsa-chief-defends-prism-phone-meta-data-collection), but no details of what that metadata includes.  Does anyone know if location is part of the metadata?

Comment: My Understanding was that Prism had to do with online snooping; The Verizon meta data collection was separate from it.

Comment: Question is still not closed?  NSA must be sleeping on the job!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [court order](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/interactive/2013/jun/06/verizon-telephone-data-court-order), under which Verizon handed over the data:

> Telephony metadata includes comprehensive communications routing
>   information,. including but not limited to session identifying
>   information (e.g., originating and terminating telephone number,
>   International Mobile Subscriber Identity (IMSI) number, International
>   Mobile station Equipment Identity (IMEI) number, etc.), trunk
>   identifier, telephone calling card numbers, and time and duration of
>   call. Telephony metadata does not include the substantive content of
>   any communication....

Given my understanding of Cell Networks, [calculating the position](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_tracking) of a cell phone, based on tower based triangulation, is quite simple in theory, but is usually not done. It is also [not very accurate](http://www.world-tracker.com/v4/how_accurate_is_it.html).  It is definitely possible for Law-enforcement Authorities to ask your service provider to provide the location of a cell phone in the past.

However the discussion is rather moot, since the above court order is silent on the matter.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain their rationale?